# jbd2 journal constant i/o

Tags: ext4, io, fstab, journaling, kjournald

`iotop` reports a constant i/o about 3% of [jbd2/vda1-8], I think this is the journal manager for ext4.

my `fstab` is:

```
UUID=X       /         ext4 defaults,noatime,nodiratime 1 1
tmpfs        /dev/shm  tmpfs    defaults,noatime,nodiratime 0 0
devpts       /dev/pts        devpts gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs        /sys      sysfs    defaults    0 0
proc         /proc     proc defaults    0 0
/usr/tmpDSK  /tmp      ext3 rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,noatime  0 0
UUID=Y       swap      swap defaults    0 0
/tmp         /var/tmp  ext3    defaults,bind,noauto
```

How can I get rid of this i/o, or at least reduce it.

Comment: I gave some details on how I tracked this down when it happened to me here: https://serverfault.com/a/801223/181704