# My HDD is constantly spinning

Tags: ubuntu, hard-disk, disk-usage

I have a dual-boot system with Ubuntu 16.04 + KDE installed on a Samsung SSD and Windows 7 installed on a WD SATA HDD.

When I run Windows the PC is quiet but when I run Ubuntu the WD SATA HDD is constantly spinning.
The most active I/O process is `jbd2/sdb1-8`.

How to make Ubuntu to spin down the Windows HDD?

```
$ less /proc/mounts # not all of the output
/dev/sdb1 / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/sda3 /media/opencv/F8089FC5089F80F4 fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
/dev/sda2 /media/opencv/5A7A21E27A21BB9F fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
/dev/sda4 /media/opencv/CE9AAEC79AAEAC01 fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0

$ fdisk -l /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb1       2048 466687999 466685952 222,5G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2       466690046 500117503  33427458    16G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       466690048 500117503  33427456    16G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

Comment: Is the Windows partition mounted on the Ubuntu system?

Comment: Ubuntu sees the disk and the partitions in it. But I think it is not auto-mounted.

Comment: If the disk is definitely not mounted Linux won't reference it and so I can't see it being a Linux issue. You could try running Linux off a recovery media and see if the problem is the same.

Comment: Tyvm :-) You can also accept the answer, by clicking the pipe icon to the left side. Ask the nvidia problem in a different question (here it is no problem if you make many questions, it is even liked, until they are voted up. Yours is now voted up).

Comment: sudo hdparm -y /dev/sda (sda as an example)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Final result: After a [remote debug session](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66260/discussion-between-nikola-obreshkov-and-peterh) in the chat, including the poweroff of his spinning hdd, was made clear that not his hdd is spinning, but the ventillator of his nvidia card.**

**Problem was solved after [installing the nVidia driver](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66260/discussion-between-nikola-obreshkov-and-peterh).**

---

*Extension: jbd2 means a kernel-based background task doing side-work on one of your **linux** filesystems, it surely doesn't do anything to your win partitions. More you can read about it [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106154/jbd2-journal-constant-i-o).*

---

This is obviously extraordinary case - if you don't use your ubuntu, it shouldn't spin your disk. There is some background process, which may not be needed (or it is, but then is it a good question, what it does).

However, fortunately there is an easy and also a more complex way to hunt this problem down.

1. Processes doing IO-intensive things are typically on the `top`. So, type: `top`, and check what is on the top. Look for processes having the `R` (=running) state in the in the `S`(tate) column. Also you can use the `ps uxa|grep R` as a purely command-line solution for the same task. Although the `top` orders the processes by their *cpu usage*, and not by their *I/O*, in most cases also the I/O intensive processes are going into the top in the `top`, as a side-effect.
2. There is a tool named [blkiomon](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-blkiomon/). Its parametrization is highly un-trivial, but you can get a much more direct info with it, who is spinning your disks and why.

The most probable causes of your problem are these:

1. Some website is doing some nasty in a rarely visited chrome tab.
2. You have not too many RAM and use some app using a lot. In this case, the cause of the spinning is the swap.

   - If it is your Chrome (what may be also because (1) ), then you may consider switching to firefox with [turned off electrolysis](https://support.mozilla.org/de/questions/1062853). It is the fastest possible way to have an useful browser with few RAM. The typical RAM-need of an e10s-free 32-bit firefox is lesser than 1G.

---

To the comments:

Which partitions are mounted and where, that you can check with the `mount` command. Unfortunately, it is filled with crap since some years, but to the end, you can see the list. Search for the lines like this:

```
/dev/sda7 on /media/archive type ext4 (rw,relatime,nobarrier,errors=remount-ro,commit=6935,data=ordered)
```

This means, that your `/dev/sda7` is mounted into the directory `/media/archive`. Sda7 is the 7th partition of your first hard disk.

---

*Extension:* As your fdisk output shows, *your SSD is your `/dev/sdb1`*.

Comment: As I said Ubuntu is installed on a SSD but the spinning noise comes from the SATA HDD where Winodws is. I have 16 GB RAM but even if I had less the swap, any logs or temp files have to be located on the SSD.

Comment: @NikolaObreshkov `jbd2/sdb1-8` means very clearly that your `/dev/sdb1` is spinned. I can't say from here, if it is your SSD or your HDD, but you can say it based on the mount table. What is mounted there, what says a `grep sdb1 /proc/mounts`?

Comment: @NikolaObreshkov It is quite extraordinary, if you can *hear* that your hdd is spinning, it means that the `/dev/sdb` is your HDD! Are you sure that really *only* a Windows is on your HDD? What says an `fdisk -l /dev/sdb`?

Comment: The PC have two discs: SSD - Ubuntu, SATA - Windows. The SATA have 3 partitions. In Windows they are C, D, E and C is where Windows is.

Comment: @NikolaObreshkov Ok. What says `fdisk -l /dev/sdb`?

Comment: Edited the question since here there are no new lines.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66260/discussion-between-nikola-obreshkov-and-peterh).